# How do you simplify a log with an exponent in the base?

Tags: logarithms

Suppose you had:

$$\log_{x^b}(y)$$

How can you simplify this? Do you use the change of base formula?

Note: I tried to come up with something similar to a homework problem without actually being a homework problem. I think this is the most simple form.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We have your original function

$$\log_{x^b}(y)=z$$
Following basic rules for logarithms, assuming $x,y,z>0$
$$(x^b)^z=y$$
$$x^{bz}=y$$
$$\log_x(y)=bz$$
Thus $z$ can be expressed as
$$z=\frac{\log_x(y)}{b}$$

Comment: I was just writing up this exact answer! @Jeff note that the laws of logs used here only apply when $x,y,b$ are all positive.

Comment: I edited the answer and added your remark.

Comment: I find it useful often to rewrite log expressions involving various bases as exponentials - it saves me some remembering of things like base change formulae, because it is easy to work out what they should be.

Comment: Actually, you want $x>1$ for this to make sense. (Log base 1 is not nice.)

Comment: There's no need for $z > 0$.  Reciprocals are permissible.

Answer (score 22):

You can calculate $$\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x^b)}=\frac{\ln(y)}{b\cdot \ln(x)}=\frac{\log_x(y)}{b}$$

Comment: this is also a very effective way